# securely send data between two jsp pages

Tags: jsp

Please help me to send  secure data like username, password from html page to ajsp page. Now the values are visibleb in the address bar when sending data. I need to hide it.
Please help me.
    
        
        
    
Please tell what changes are made to the above code for securly send values.

Comment: Look for `JSP session` in your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, security it's not a easy thing...

What you can do to avoid parameters in address bar it's to change your method to `method="POST"` in the `<form>` TAG. In this way you'll have data sent in request body and not in URL params.

Furthermore you can join the two data and encode them upon a public key thru javascript, so the data in request can be decrypted only by JSP (owning the private key)...

But remember that if you're out of a secure protocol (ie. `https`) each data will be easily readable: you can hash, encrypt, do whatever, but if someone is "listening" to the communications beetwen server and client, he could recover data quite easily.

There are many other methods to send data encrypted, but each one has its pros and cons, there's barely always a 'weak link', the right choice depends on what you have to protect and from whom.

Comment: I mostly agree, but if a securely hashed password is transmitted in the clear, an attacker would still have a hard time deciphering the password if it uses a strong algorithm and salt, such as SHA512. Although I would never recommend it, I would still consider it pretty safe especially if you regularly change your password.